# Random Ubuntu 19.10 freezing issue

Tags: 19.10, amd-ryzen

I'm hoping you guys can help me, this is my first linux build. I've played around with Ubuntu a little bit (Surface Pro 3) but this is my first daily-driver. I purchased all new parts for this build, and ever since the first install I've been having spontaneous freezing - the whole system is locked up. Terminal disconnects, nomachine disconnects, and it stops responding to pings. The HDD light will either be stuck on or off, depending on where it was during the stop. Sometimes it will be days, sometimes it will be an hour or two. I thought it was only during low idle, but it recently happened under moderate load - I was running a VM.

I'm coming from Windows so I'm a little lost with the logs and what they would actually mean. I can't reproduce the issue and it's seemingly at-random. I've gathered up a few in the hopes that you can maybe shed some light? I've read all about Ryzen 5, processor cstates, b450 BIOS issues, tried memtest, don't have temperature issues.

Today there was an update for the mesa drivers, and that seems to have made things worse. Is there a way to roll those back at least?

I installed crash but I don't think its installed right - either way I have a ton of those files too. At this point I'm not sure if it's a software/Ubuntu thing or if I should be RMA'ing my hardware. Can you help me Reddit?

Summary

ASRock Fatal1ty b450 Gaming-ITX/ax P3.70

Ryzen 5 3600X

MSI Radeon R7 240 2 GB Video Card

Corsair Vengeance LPX 32 GB (2 x 16 GB) DDR4-3200 Memory

EVGA SuperNOVA GM 450 W 80+ Gold

Samsung 500GB 970 Evo nvme

dmesg, journalctl, and ixns info:

https://github.com/NickSalacious/LinuxErrors

Edit: Initially I had lock ups when attempting to install directly from a bootable ISO. I had to go into 'try ubuntu' and install from there. I've also partitioned the nvme drive and put 18 LTS on it - same issues just not as bad. After the mesa driver update yesterday the 19.10 version will spontaneously reboot now. UGH!

Edit#2: I've noticed this only happens on some builds. On the ones that DON'T crash, I see these messages when I update-initramfs:

W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/vega20_ta.bin for module amdgpu

W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_mes.bin for module amdgpu

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104029/discussion-on-question-by-nicksalacious-random-ubuntu-19-10-freezing-issue).

Answer (score 0):

Might not still be relevent, but I just made a new PC build with a Ryzen 7 3700x 8-core processor and was having random lockups/freezing normally after between 5-30 minutes on Ubuntu 19.10 too.

After trying loads of workarounds, I just tried out of curiosity Ubuntu 20.04 (as it came out a day later), and I've now been working on it for the last 2 hours with no problems.

Maybe some of the kernal/zenstate updates in 20.04 has solved the problems.